# How to save a list of recent text entries in isolated storage.?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

In my app I have a textbox named "msgBox" and a button named "sendBtn".
When the user taps the Button, the text typed in the msgBox is sent to a server.

I want to save and display the last 15-20 sent items.
How can I do that..??

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the most recent items, you could include the current date with the submission of the form. Then, when accessing the server, sort the items by their date, and only display the first 15-20. This method would be simpler than creating another table dedicated to recent entries. Also, browsing through archives by date would be much easier as the date would be tagged to the entries.

As a mySQL statement (being the server language I know the most), inserting a message would be the following (where [message] is the sanitized MsgBox value):

```
INSERT INTO `messages` (`msg`,`date`) VALUES ('[message]',NOW());
```

Retrieval would look like so:

```
SELECT `msg` FROM `messages` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 15;
```

This method would be simpler than creating another table dedicated to recent entries. Also, browsing through archives by date would be much easier as the date would be tagged to the entries.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Appreciate your effort.
But I am not looking for this.
I am looking to store a "list" in isolated storage.
I cant find a way to do that.!